# How to use "minDateTime" API in @mui/x-date-pickers?

Tags: reactjs, mui-x

I have to disable past Date with Time in MUI MobileDateTimePicker component.

I have a MUI Form component with a MUI Calendar component consists of @mui/x-date-pickers (MobileDateTimePicker). I have to disable past Date with Time. I already used 'minDate' API & it works perfectly. But, it disables only past dates. I have to disable dates till current time. How to I do it ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.